# Precise the attachment extension .PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code already send an email with attachment, the extension is not indicated though.

Also, can you explain me how to name the attachment as this pattern:

Pré-emploi - CandidateName.PDF

I tried to change the name  on this line "`var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");`"
Also, I tried to add var CandidateName at the end of this line

```
var blob = newSpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf').setName(spreadsheet.getName()+ " - ".CandidateName);
```

---

```
function emailAsPDF() {
  var emailAddress=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var mess="Voulez-vous envoyer votre rapport  à l'adresse : " + emailAddress;
  var ans= Browser.msgBox("Courriel", mess, Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  if (ans===Browser.Buttons.NO){return;}
  var mess="Votre rapport a été envoyé à l'adresse : " + emailAddress;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Recherche");
  //var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var CandidateName=ss.getRangeByName("Nom.Candidat").getValue();
  var emailSubject="Vérifications pré-emploi complétées" +" - "+ CandidateName;
  var emailMessage="Bonjour," + "\n\n" + "J’ai le plaisir de vous informer que les vérifications sont complétées pour le candidat indiqué au tableau de résultats pré-emploi suivant:" + "\n\n" + "Bonne journée !";
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//.getSheetByName("Formation");
  var sheet=spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Recherche");
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
  sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
  var sheetNames=newSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
  var blob = newSpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf').setName(spreadsheet.getName());
  var folderID = parentFolder(); // Folder id to save the PDF
  Logger.log(folderID);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob);
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailMessage,{attachments:[pdfFile]});
  //DriveApp.getFileById(pdfFile.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);  
  DriveApp.getFileById(pdfFile.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  Browser.msgBox("Courriel", mess, Browser.Buttons.OK); 
}


function parentFolder() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()); 
  var ParentFolder= file.getParents();
  while ( ParentFolder.hasNext() ) {
    var folder = ParentFolder.next();
    folderID=folder.getId();
     Logger.log(folderID);
  }
  return folderID;
}

function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()); 
  var ParentFolder= file.getParents();
  var folder = ParentFolder.next();
   Logger.log(folder);
//  while ( ParentFolder.hasNext() ) {
//    var folder = ParentFolder.next();
//    folderID=folder.getId();
//     Logger.log(folderID);
//  }
//  return folderID;
}
```

I expect to receive a PDF attachment named this way:
Pré-emploi - CandidateName
Also, how can I change the document orientation ?

If you need access to the file, just ask me.

Comment: For the name part, can you try using this instead? `var blob = newSpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf').setName(spreadsheet.getName()+ " - " + CandidateName);`. Replacing the *period* with an addition `+` sign.

Comment: I put this code: 
var blob = newSpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf')+ setName(spreadsheet.getName()+ " - " + CandidateName); 

but it gives this error: ReferenceError: "setName" is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Rather than setting the name of the `blob` on creation, you need to set the name of the file on creation.*

#### Code:

```js
function emailPDF() {
  // previous code...
  var blob = newSpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf').setName(spreadsheet.getName());
  // code...
  var pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob);
}
```

Needs to be changed to:

```js
function emailPDF() {
  // previous code...
  var blob = newSpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf');
  // code...
  var pdfName = spreadsheet.getName() + " - " + CandidateName + '.pdf';
  var pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob).setName(pdfName);
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! this helped to solve the adding name issue.
Now, is it possible to receive the attachment with the extension .pdf ?
Here is the picture:
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=502217785914

Comment: @Mous Try appending `+ '.pdf'` after `CanditateName` in the assignment of `pdfName`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciated it :)

Answer (score 0):

Perfect ! this helped to solve the adding name issue.
Now, is it possible to receive the attachment with the extension .pdf ?
Here is the picture:
[image: https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=502217785914]